# Android internet connectivity issue

Tags: android

I have developed an Android app which uses web service to get data. This means it requires an internet connection. My problem is when the internet is not available during web service call or before web service call it should throw some alerts.

I have implemented one code:

```
 public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        try {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        URL url = new URL("https://widget.istockanalyst.com/WebServiceIStock.asmx");
        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url
        .openConnection();
        urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "My Android Demo");
        urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000); // mTimeout is in seconds

        urlc.connect();

        if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200)
        {
            System.out.println("*********True****************");
            
        return true;
        
        
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("*********False****************");   
            
        return false;
        
        }
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
        }
```

And after that I'm calling this method on my splash screen. And on emulator it is responding, but when I perform device testing after disabling the WiFi it is showing an error and app crashes.

Comment: Can you post your Logcat Message

Comment: I don't know much about Android development, but I'm betting the error/stacktrace would help those here who do help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because

```
cm.getActiveNetworkInfo()
```

returns null, therefore when you call

```
.isConnectedOrConnecting())
```

a java.lang.NullPointerException is thrown. A better way to do this would be to test if getActiveNetworkInfo() returns null

```
        public boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting())
            return true;
        return false;
}
```

Hope this helps.